# IList<IWhatever> as a method parameter

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have two `IList<ICat>` and I'm trying to create a method which takes an `IList<ICat>` and does some work. I'm having problems trying to pass either an `IList<PussyCat>` or `IList<OtherCat>` to it, both `PussyCat` and `OtherCat` implement `ICat`.

I've tried:

```
List<PussyCat> cats = ...
DoWork((IList<ICat>)cats);
```

and just

```
DoWork(cats);
```

But neither compile. Any ideas?

Comment: please show signature of your Dowork() method...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C# generics are invariant. It means `List<string>` is not a `List<object>`.

C# 4.0 introduces [*safe* covariance/contravariance](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2009/04/13/c-4-0-feature-focus-part-4-generic-co-and-contra-variance-for-delegate-and-interface-types.aspx) but still, you wouldn't be able to pass `List<string>` as `List<object>`. The reason is:

```
List<string> x = new List<string>();
List<object> o = x; // assume this statement is valid
o.Add(5); // Adding an integer to a list of strings. Unsafe. Will throw.
```

Arrays, on the other hand are covariant. You can pass a `string[]` to a method that expects `object[]`.

Comment: Thank you. I have read about co- and contra-variance, but I think a more thorough reading on my part is needed. I'm finding I 'need' C# 4.0 more and more.

Comment: Note that if `DoWork` is just `foreach`ing the collection and not changing anything, you can declare the parameter as `IEnumerable<ICat>` and call it with `DoWork(cats.Cast<ICat>())`.

Answer (score 5):

There are two alternatives:

1. Make your method like this:

   ```
   public void DoWork< T > (IList< T > cats_) where T : ICat
   {
       //Do work;
   }
   ```
2. The other possibility is to have a method like

   ```
   public void DoWork(IList< ICat > cats_) 
   {
       //Do work;
   }
   ```

   and call it in the following manner:

   ```
   {
       //....Assuming: IList<PussyCat> iListOfPussyCats
       List<PussyCat> pussyCats = new List<PussyCats>(iListOfPussyCats);
       DoWork(pussyCats.ConvertAll<ICat>( c => c as ICat);
   }
   ```

Comment: +1 for the generic version (Note that this is not inefficient in any way: At runtime one generic instance with T = ICat will be used for all possible cases)

Answer (score 1):

If the method doesn't truly require direct indexing (`IList<T>`) and doesn't require adding/removing items (`ICollection<T>`), then pass an `IEnumerable<T>`. The `Cast<T>()` extension methods allow casting any `IList` of [insert `ICat`-derived type] to be passed as an `IEnumerable<ICat>`.

Answer (score 0):

Till C# 4.0 arrives which has support for co and contra variance you might be able to get away with something like this:

```
public void DoWork(IEnumerable<ICat> cats)
{
  //do something 
}
 List<PussyCat> pussyCats = new List<PussyCat>;
 List<OtherCat> otherCats = new List<OtherCat>;
 DoWork(pussyCats.OfType<ICat>);
 DoWork(otherCats.OfType<ICat>);
```

Comment: As I said, nothing will change with C# 4.0 for this specific situation and `OfType` returns `IEnumerable` not `IList`.